# Error installing aircrack-ng during make step, something about HMAC?

Tags: kali-linux, make, aircrack-ng

I'm trying to install aircrack-ng in kali rolling, and I'm trying to use the make function, but I get an error saying something about a file named HMAC_CTX:

```
crypto.c: In function 'calc_mic':
crypto.c:291:11: error: storage size of 'ctx' isn't known
HMAC_CTX ctx;
   ^~~
crypto.c:317:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 
'HMAC_CTX_init' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
crypto.c:327:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 
'HMAC_CTX_cleanup' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
crypto.c:291:11: warning: unused variable 'ctx' [-Wunused-variable]
HMAC_CTX ctx;
   ^~~
crypto.c: In function 'calc_tkip_mic_key':
crypto.c:932:5: warning: this 'if' clause does not guard... [-
Wmisleading-indentation]
if((ptr-message) % 4 > 0)
^~
crypto.c:933:49: note: ...this statement, but the latter is 
misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the 'if'
 memcpy(ptr, ZERO, 4-((ptr-message)%4)); ptr+=4-((ptr-
message)%4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a definition problem, you can discard the warnings here, the source code is outdated

the actual code snippet from that location seems like

```
#if defined(USE_GCRYPT) || OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10100000L
    #define HMAC_USE_NO_PTR
#endif

#ifdef HMAC_USE_NO_PTR
HMAC_CTX ctx;
#else
HMAC_CTX * ctx;
#endif
```

you need to update your repo with `apt-get update` and then install it again, or if you are compiling it, download a more recent source code